# canvas animation weirdly behaves like a step function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

and by that i mean, chunks of frames will execute super fast, and then pause in between the chunks for a long time (4-6k milliseconds)

its defined clearly to be on an interval every 42ms. instead, after the first call, there is a pause, then 5-6 iterations come in a burst (you can see with logging). it goes through the sprite sheet properly when it goes through iterations, the iterations are just not happening every 42ms 1 at a time.

only testing on chrome since im going to plug this into Electron later. but first i have to figure this out.

this is the js, only html is 
`<canvas id="person1"></canvas>`

```
var people = [];

    var p1_canvas = document.getElementById("person1");
    p1_canvas.width = 321;
    p1_canvas.height = 571;

    var p1_img = new Image();
    p1_img.src = "person1.png";

    var person1 = {x:0,y:0,f:1,max_x:3852-321,max_y:55958-571,canvas:p1_canvas,img:p1_img,width:321,height:571,name:"person1",playing:false};
    people[person1.name] = person1;

    function talk(person){
        if(!person.playing){return;}

        if(person.x == person.max_x){ //next row or at end 3852/12=321
            if(person.y == person.max_y){ //at end 55958/98=571
                person.x=0; person.y=0; person.f=0;
            } else { //next row
                person.x=0; person.y+=571;
            }
        } else { //same row, move 321 to the right
            person.x+=321;
        }

        console.log("frame: "+person.f+" coords:"+person.x+","+person.y); person.f++;
        //clear old frame and move to x,y
        var context = person.canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.clearRect(0,0,person.width,person.height);

        context.drawImage(person.img,person.x,person.y,person.width,person.height,0,0,person.width,person.height);

    }

    function play(person){ person.playing = true; person.interval = window.setInterval(function(){talk(person1);},42); }
    function stop(person){ person.playing = false; window.clearInterval(person.interval); }
```

Comment: Make your code executable

Comment: @SPMai, There is a little button on stackoverflow which allows you to make your code executable. Look here: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=101502

Comment: you can copy paste my js + html into a file and open it in a browser to test...

there are no console errors, the animation just doesnt render smoothly or on-time in browser

Comment: Thats not the point of my comment. I said that you should always make your code executable if possible.

Comment: i just dont see why its relevant here, is all. but in general i will remember

Comment: it is for the ones who try to help you so they can better understand what you try to do...

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea (I can't comment yet) : 
I find in SO that using a variable (person1) with the same name as a DOM element id could be messy. Because an object person1 is created with this id.

Comment: thanks for the comment. ill try to rename and let you know if it makes a difference. however, what do you mean by 'SO'?

Comment: SO = stackoverflow

Comment: in my actual page i did try renaming the variable, and no difference, the animation doesnt go smoothly although the code executes smoothly, im not sure if its a performance issue or because my sprites are too large